# How can I refer to a named color located in package library's Assets.xcassets?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am developing a package library, so that I can share the code among multiple extensions.

I want to refer to a named color located in package's library `Assets.xcassets`.

[image]

The following code, which is written in the package library, is not working as expected.

```
let testColor = Color("whiteNoteColor")
```

It was not able locate **whiteNoteColor** defined in `Assets.xcassets`.

May I know, what is the correct way to do so? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to specify the bundle when the asset is held as part of a package. Try

```
let testColor = Color("whiteNoteColor", bundle: .module)
```

Note that this can be a little sketchy in SwiftUI previews, depending on the target.

If you want to access these colours outside the package, you should expose them as public properties defined like the above code - don't try and make `Bundle.module` public or let outside code try to use the named assets. It doesn't end well.

Answer (score 0):

To read the color from the assets, you must call it as a `UIColor(named:)` and turn it to type `Color`.

You can easily access the color by creating an extension to the type `Color`, than it becomes a color like any other.

Like this:

```
extension Color {
    
    static var whiteNoteColor: Color { Color(UIColor(named: "whiteNoteColor") ?? UIColor(Color.white)) }
}
```

You use it in your code:

```
Text("My text in white")
    .foregroundColor(.whiteNoteColor)  // Cal it as if it were a system color
```